# How do I get all children that fall under a multiple parent id using eloquent for three level structure?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, tree, treeview, laravel-blade

I was getting an output like this  parent

```
child 1 ==> level 1
    Sub-child 1 ==> level 2
        sub-Sub-child  ==> level 3      
    Sub-child 2  ==> level 2
        sub-Sub-child ==> level 3
```

What I need is to get an o/p like this. This was the database structure:

[image]

Each and every level to be view in level wise tables in laravel blade can anyone help to solve this parent

```
child 1 ==> level 1 child 2 ==> level 1 child 3 ==> level 1

Sub-child 1 ==> level 2 Sub-child 2 ==> level 2 Sub-child 3 ==> level 2

sub-Sub-child 3 ==> level 3 sub-Sub-child 3 ==> level 3 sub-Sub-child 3 ==> level 3
```

Code I was using in eloquent orm:

```
public function childs()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model  \clients','under_reference','reference_id','id')
    ->leftjoin('clients_payment_type', function($join) {
    $join->on('clients_payment_type.user_id', '=', 'clients.id');
    });
 }
```

Code I was using in view blade

```
@foreach($childs as $child)
   @if(count($child->GrandChild) > 0 )
      @include('AdminLayout.levelTwo',['childs' => $child->childs])
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Same as continues in laravel blade for level one 2 and three can anyone help me to solve this...

Comment: I would suggest having a look at https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#220 ▼
    #items: array:5 [▼
      0 => App\clients {#221 ▶}
      1 => App\clients {#224 ▶}
      2 => App\clients {#225 ▶}
      3 => App\clients {#226 ▶}
      4 => App\clients {#227 ▶}
    ]
  }
]